# Maven Clean Fails on Linux Vagrant Shared Drive

Tags: maven, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vagrant

Using vagrant, I `git clone`'d my java app to `c:/shared`. In my `Vagrantfile`, I specified that my host's `c:/shared` will be mapped to `/home/vagrant/myapp` on my Virtual Machine.

When I run `mvn clean compile` from within the VM, I ran into this error:

```
core/myapp/target/classes/com/myapp/...
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.CleanMojo.execute(CleanMojo.java:215)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to delete core/myapp/target/classes/com/myapp/...
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete(Cleaner.java:249)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete(Cleaner.java:191)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.clean.Cleaner.delete(Cleaner.java:158)
```

However, the Maven build succeeds on my Windows (host) machine.

Running `ls` gives an odd output as the privileges show up as question marks(?):

```
[vagrant-centos65 parent]$ ls -lrot target/...
ls: cannot access ...
?????????? ? ? ?            ? $Class$$doMethod$1$1$$anonfun$apply$2.class
```

I'm running as user `kevin`, where as `/home/vagrant/myapp` is owned by `vagrant`. However, most, if not all, of `myapp`'s directories have wide open (`766` or `777`) rights.

In the past, I've successfully compiled on the guest VM in a directory shared between host and guest.

I'm using:

```
vagrant - 1.3.5
Maven - 3.2.1
VirtualBox - 4.3.8
```

Also, I observed that this particular folder (`C:`) is not being indexed per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3910746/409976).

**EDIT** I'm seeing the same error even when hosting the file with [smb](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/smb.html).

Why would the build succeed on the host, but not the guest?

Comment: Which vagrant version? Which synced type folder?

Comment: vagrant 1.3.5. I never specified the sync. I'm using Windows on host

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During compilation, Maven compiled Scala source files into `CLASS` files.

The length of one `.class` file was **161**. The path's length to this file was ~100.

> 161 + ~90 = ~261 # exceeds the 255 path length on Windows

In order to fix this problem, @monkjack informed me how to limited the length of a generated CLASS file to 75 characters - https://stackoverflow.com/a/23138361/409976.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem, but mainly because I was dumb and had Eclipse running on the host with a project in the shared area abd 'build automatically' selected.

So every time maven deleted a target file, eclipse would recreate it...