# Specifying Scalac Compile-Time Option with maven-scala-plugin

Tags: scala, maven

Using the `maven-scala-plugin 2.15.2`, I'm trying to specify the max length of a Scala Class File to "50" characters. I tried 2 places in my `pom.xml`:

```
    <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.15.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <scalacArgs>   <-- Attempt #1 -->
                                    <scalacArg>-Xmax-classfile-name 50</scalacArg> 
                                </scalacArgs> 
                                <scalaVersion>${scalaVer}</scalaVersion>
                                <args>
                                    <arg>-make:transitive</arg>
                                    <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
                                    <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
<!-- Attempt #2 -->
                                </args>

                            </configuration>
```

I also ran `mvn compile -Xmax-classfile-name 50`, but Maven did not recognize the option and failed.

Where can I specify this option using the `maven-scala-plugin`?

Comment: maven-scala-plugin is deprecated (since more than 2 years) please use scala-maven-plugin. (creator of the 2 plugins)

Comment: thanks for the heads-up, David. And thanks for the plugins

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Where you are using `args` inside `configuration` should be where you put your compiler args. You seem to have also created `scalacArgs`, but the `args` are passed to scalac.

I use this in my plugin to pass options to the compiler:

`<configuration>
    <args>
        <arg>-g:vars</arg>
        <arg>-Yrangepos</arg>
        <arg>-P:scoverage:dataDir:${coverage.data.dir}</arg>
        <arg>-Xmax-classfile-name</arg>
        <arg>70</arg>
    </args>
    <jvmArgs>
        <jvmArg>-Xms64m</jvmArg>
        <jvmArg>-Xmx1024m</jvmArg>
    </jvmArgs>
    <compilerPlugins>
        <compilerPlugin>
            <groupId>org.scoverage</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalac-scoverage-plugin_${scala.major}</artifactId>
            <version>${scoverage-plugin.version}</version>
        </compilerPlugin>
    </compilerPlugins>
</configuration>`

http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/maven-scala-plugin/example_compile.html#Compiler_Arguments

Comment: Maven 3 didn't know how to handle `<arg>-Xmax-classfile-name:50</arg>`: **[ERROR] scalac error: bad option: '-Xmax-classfile-name:50'**. I also got the same error when using a space and equals delimiter, i.e. rather than `:` between the option and the value.

Comment: Maven just passes them to scalac. Try my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, @monkjack. That worked. As a slight proposed edit, the argument to `-Xmax-classfile-name` needs to be between `~70` and some other number (I don't remember)